# How to impose restriction over a simple element while defining a xsd

Tags: xsd

I am trying to impose some restrictions over my data type in a simple element like

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:element name="person" type="personType"/>
    <xs:complexType name="personType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="first-name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="last-name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="age" type="xs:integer">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

but I am getting an error like: `the 'type' attribute and an anonymous type definitions are mutually exclusive for element declaration 'age'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
                <xs:element name="age" type="xs:integer">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
               </xs:element>
```

to

```
       <xs:element name="age">
                    <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                                <xs:maxInclusive value="100"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                    </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```